# Проблема сборки из исходников CromiumOS

Tags: virtualbox, chromium

Пытаюсь собрать из исходников ChromiumOS для виртуальной машины Virtual Box. Делаю все по инструкции, как написано на оф. сайте в руководстве по сборке. Успешно получилось собрать ./build_packages и ./build_image. Однако, при попытке выполнить команду ./image_to_vm сборка прерывается ошибкой: [image: Информация об ошибке]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь в исправлении данной ошибки.

В интернете очень мало готовых виртуальных машин с ChromeOS. Может у кого есть ссылочка какая-нибудь. Буду особо благодарен!)

Comment: раньше пользовался www.neverware.com, но это Chromium OS, а Chrome OS она вроде как не открытая

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправлю вопрос, это и есть Chromium OS